# How to format cells to add % at the end of every cell

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to add % at the end of every cell value.

I have tried formatting the cells by going to the format cells -> custom -> type: 0.00%.

But this will multiply all the cell values by 100.

```
-0.031514839
-0.013255332
-0.007855065
```

I dont want to modify the cell value instead I just want to add % character at the end of every cell.

Comment: A percentage is a fraction so `0` is `0%`,  `1` is `100%`, `0.5` is `50%` and so on

Comment: See, if I format as 0% I get: -3%, -1% and -1%. If I do 0.00%, I get: -3.15%, -1.32%. What I am asking is, I dont want to get the value modified instead I just need to add % symbol at the end of value without modifying.

Comment: You will need to use a helper column to do the math. For example do `=--(A1&"%")` then format the column as percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple method is I just divided by 100 in the formula and added the cell format of 0.00%. S0, that the effect will be neutralized!

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom format of:

```
0.##############"%"
```

[image]

When using a custom format, putting a `0` ensures that a number will appear in that space. If it's a non-zero number, that number will show.  The `#` means that a value will show *only* if a number exists in that position.

From [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68) (See "Decimal places, spaces, colors, and conditions")

> Use the number sign (#) if you want to display only the significant digits in a number. This sign does not allow the display non-significant zeros.
>
> Use the numerical character for zero (0) if you want to display non-significant zeros when a number might have fewer digits than have been specified in the format code.

Some simple examples:
[image]

Comment: @chan - Did you use exactly as I posted? With the values you gave in OP, I get the screenshot where it doesn't multiply.  Note there are quotes around the `%` --> `"%"`.

Comment: it works! thanks. # means any digits? It even works with 72.768693938. Why is there a single 0 before the decimal? This explanation would help others too. TIA!

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it right.
Use a backslash in front of % to prevent the 100x multiplication !

**Format -> Custom ->  enter `0.00\%`**